# Evgrafov, Beardon and Cartan: how do they compare?

Tags: complex-analysis, book-recommendation

I graduated from university very long ago and I have forgotten most of what I learned in class, but I want to re-learn some mathematics again. I am reading Henri Cantan's [*Elementary Theory of Analytic Functions of One or Several Complex Variables*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0486685438) right now, but I don't feel like I understand the subject very well.

Recently, I found that Dover was going to republish two titles on complex analysis this year:

- M.A. Evgrafov's [*Analytic Functions*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0486837602),
- Alan Beardon's [*Complex Analysis: The Argument Principle in Analysis and Topology*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0486837181).

I am thinking whether I should abandon Cartan and make a switch to one of these two books instead, but I can only find a very short [review](https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/mathematical-gazette/article/complex-analysis-the-argument-principle-in-analysis-and-topology-by-a-f-beardon-pp-xiii-239-14-1979-sbn-0-471-99671-8-wiley/DEE17FF9D599D08A82CF568FA17FCAC3) of Beardon's book by Victor Bryant (the author of *Yet Another Introduction to Analysis*).

Is anybody familiar with the two aforementioned books? What are their strengths and weaknesses? For beginners, are they better than Cartan or well suited for self study?

At my current level, I don't think I can deal with more advanced topics, but I would like to read a clear, rigorous and efficient development of Cauchy's theorem and many worked examples of using residue calculus to calculate integrals.

Comment: do you have some familiarity with multivariable calculus? For example, the notions of partial derivatives?

Comment: I dont know much about other books but I would suggest having a look at https://www.amazon.in/Complex-Analysis-Mathematics-Engineering-Mathew/dp/817319761X

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik Yes, I do, but I want a proof of Cauchy's theorem without assuming that function has *continuous* partial derivatives.

Comment: If you have the math background, Narasimhan has a very nice proof of the Looman Menchoff theorem in my opinion. His book can be a little tough though. I would recommend starting with a basic complex analysis text, then graduate onto something on the level of Ahlfors, then move onto Narasimhan. You can technically skip any step there because each level covers the stuff below it, but you will inevitably miss out on basic skills and intuition in so doing

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen Thanks. I don't know there is such a theorem! But at this stage, I only want to learn some undergraduate complex analysis as if I am a beginner.

Comment: @WilliamMcGonagall I'll give you a proper answer when I have time soon (assuming you don't get a better one before that)